# Why is it true that $\int\int f(x-t)g(t)dtdx = \int f(x)dx \int g(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

This appears in a proof on page 122 of *Measure and Integral* by Wheeden and Zygmund. The theorem is that

> If $f,g$ are Lebesgue integrable functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, then $(f*g)(x)$ exists for almost every $\mathbf x\in \mathbb R^n$ and is measurable. Morevover, $f*g$ is Lebesgue integrable and$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f*g|d\mathbf x \le \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|d\mathbf x\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |g|d\mathbf x\right),$$ $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} (f*g)d\mathbf x \le \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} fd\mathbf x\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} gd\mathbf x\right).$$

On the last few line of the proof, they say by Fubini's theorem, $\int f(\mathbf {x} -\mathbf t)g(\mathbf t) d\mathbf t$ exists for a.e. $\mathbf x$ and is measurable and integrable; also, $$\int\int f(x-t)g(t)dtdx = \int \left[\int f(x-t)g(t)dt \right] dx = \int f(x)dx \int g(x)dx.$$

Why does the last equality hold? I guessed they use change of variable? How do they change the variable?

Comment: Change the order of integration. $\int f(x-t)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dx$ by the translation-invariance of the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be 
$$\int \int f(x-t) g(t) \, dt \, dx = \int \left( \int f(x-t)g(t) \, dx \right) dt = \int \left( \int f(x-t) \, dx \right) g(t) \, dt, $$
because $g(t)$ is independent of $x$. Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant, so $\int f(x-t) \, dx = \int f(x) \, dx $, and then this independent of $t$, so
$$ \int \left( \int f(x) \, dx \right) g(t) \, dt = \left( \int f(x) \, dx \right) \int g(t) \, dt $$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fubini to express it as
$$
\int g(t)\left( \int f(x-t) dx \right) dt.
$$
Then because Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, the bracket is independent of $t$ and coincides with $\int f(x) dx$.  Pull it out and you arrive at the desired expression.